# Cucumber gherkin script - want to test a scenario having a background with multiple test data

Tags: java, gherkin, cucumber-java

After going through other online sources, I understand that we cannot have background with multiple test data. I have set of scenarios which are to add users with different privileges and they have common steps to log in at first, which would be my background as it needs to execute for every scenario. 
Sample of my scenario

```
    Background: Admin or Super Admin Login    
    Given Open browser and navigate "xyz" server
    When Give user credentials "<username>" and "<password>"
        |username|password|
        |Admin | 123|
        |SuperAdmin| 123|
    Then User selects a client
    And  Click on Go To Dashboard
    Then User should be able to log in


    @UserPage
    Scenario: Admin or super admin user add a new user with admin rights

    When Admin user adds a new user
    And User fills in all the required information
        |username|Client|Password|Retype Password | Email| Admin |
        Test data 
    And Add new user personal information
        |FirstName|LastName|Phone|
        Test data
    Then User with admin rights is created.
```

My requirement is that Admin and super admin user (both have different privileges) can create a new user with or without admin rights.
So, my question here is how can I test this scenario with different logged in users, so the background and scenario should be executed once for Admin user and once for super admin.

Any leads on the recommended way to write and execute this gherkin script?
Thank You.

Comment: You can use a ScenarioOutline to run the scenario for the two admins by creating an examples table with admin login details. Problem is steps in background will not pick up data from the examples table. You could condense the background steps into a super step and include it within the actual scenariooutline itself.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your response. @Grasshopper
I have code implementation for background already, this background is my scenario is another feature file, so I was looking for code reusability. 
So there is no way to reuse existing scenario?

Comment: You can still call the existing methods from the "super" single step method for the login part. Re-usability will be still there but gherkin steps for login will be condensed. But maintainability will definitely be an issue. One more thing the description "Admin or super admin user add.... " can be created dynamically by picking up user type from the examples table if you add an additional 'admintype' column and changing the desc to "<admintype> user add... "

Comment: Thank you, that would work. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Grasshopper, I tried using a placeholder in scenario outline, it gives lexing error.
Link to the error code - https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/aBzCBvZjp7SyvR4HzPP--w

Comment: which is line 10? Also there is no data in the datatable.

Comment: Lexing error usually, because of the format. check the format of the feature file.

Comment: @Grasshopper, my line 10 is  
Scenario Outline: Happy '<admintype>' user can add a new user with admin rights

Comment: Thank you @Murthi the lexing error was because of the format issue. There was a space in between scenario outline and Colon
**Scenario outline :** instead it should be **Scenario outline:**

Comment: Thanks, @Grasshopper. It is now working.

Answer (score 0):

As Grasshopper said, you can condense the background steps as given below. It may resolve your issue.

```
    Background: Admin or Super Admin Login    
        Given Open browser and navigate "xyz" server
    @UserPage
    Scenario Outline: "<username>" user add a new user with admin rights
        When Give user credentials "<username>" and "<password>"
        Then User selects a client
        And  Click on Go To Dashboard
        Then User should be able to log in
        When Admin user adds a new user
        And User fills in all the required information
            |username|Client|Password|Retype Password | Email| Admin |
            Test data 
        And Add new user personal information
            |FirstName|LastName|Phone|
            Test data
        Then User with admin rights is created.

    Examples:
        |username   |password|
        |Admin      | 123    |
        |SuperAdmin | 123    |
```